# How to set initial value of a field using foreign field of a model in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I wish to set initial value in profile form.

Profile model has a OneToOne relation with User model.

I get the following error when I set initial field in **init** method,

> 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'email'

**Traceback**

> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in get
>     190.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in get
>     133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
>
> File "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/users/views.py" in
>   get_context_data
>     90.         context = super(ProfileSettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in get_context_data
>     66.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
>
> File
>   "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/venv_ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in get_form
>     33.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
>
> File "/home/drogon/Crowdsocial_project/users/forms.py" in **init**
>     144.         self.initial['profile_email'] = Profile.user.email
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/12/profile/settings Exception
>   Value: 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'email'

**Profile Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Profile Form**

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    full_name      = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    profile_email  = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.initial['profile_email'] = Profile.user.email
        self.initial['full_name'] = Profile.user.name

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = ['image','full_name','biography','profile_email','linked_in','facebook',
                  'twitter','phone','education']
```

Comment: use it `self.initial['profile_email'] = models.Profile.objects.get(id=1)['email']`

Comment: I see that you want to use the user information and prefil this in your form. But is the user signed in everytime he/she visits the form?